# Table used in cursor select is restructured from compile-time to run-time

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, runtime-error, teradata

I'm getting  `CALL Failed.  [7691] SP_name:Table used in cursor select is restructured from compile-time to run-time.`

I believe its because I have loop over dates in my stored procedure:

```
If min_mnth <= max_mnth THEN
        LoopMnth:
        FOR cc_mnth AS cc_cdates CURSOR FOR
            SELECT To_Char(calendar.calendar_date, 'yyyy-mm') as mnth
            from sys_calendar.calendar
            where To_Char(calendar.calendar_date, 'yyyy-mm') between min_mnth and max_mnth
            and mnth not in (select report_mnth from tb1)
            and mnth >= '2017-08'
            group by 1 order by 1
.....
```

Interesting fact, that that such procedure sometimes work, mostly then I had less  loop iterations.

I have found only this relevant information https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Error-7691-P1-Table-used-in-cursor-select-is-restructured-from/td-p/36691

They suggests `SET SESSION DATEFORM = INTEGERDATE` - same error.

What is this error about and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm out of my league on this one, but just wanted to double check that you ran that `SET SESSION DATEFORM = INTEGERDATE`, then compiled the procedure (not ran, but compiled). Then after that attempted to run. I imagine you did and this is a "Did you turn the computer on and off again" type question, but it wasn't stated in your question.

Comment: Also, honestly, I feel like this is getting into "Bug" territory, so if you don't get any traction here, I would toss this onto Teradata Forums stating the steps you've taken and have one of the folks with their hands in the bits and bytes of teradata to dive into it. (unless @dnoeth is already running it down because he's crazy wicked smart and connected like that).

Comment: Guess that, @JNevill, ?) I recompiled the proc with that option - now seems work fine, but anyway this quite strange problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you get such error, just

```
1) SET SESSION DATEFORM = INTEGERDATE
2) Recreate your procedure
```